# Angular Syncfusion Scheduler - Set color to a single event

Tags: angular, scheduler, syncfusion, angular-scheduler, ejs-schedule

I am using Angular EJ2 Syncfusion Scheduler, but I am not able to set a separate color for each event, I can only set a color to a group of events which are in the same row.

Example: In the following scheduler I would like to set the blue color for **David** and red color for **Peter**. I can only set the same color to a row of events, but not to a single event.

https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/demos/?_ga=2.228039129.553863759.1586967379-1144123233.1586967379#/material/schedule/external-drag-drop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background color for the events is set based on the **colorField**. If we want to set the separate color for each event, we should remove the **colorField** and include the custom field in the event object to maintain the color.

```
 {
    Id: 10,
    Name: "David",
    StartTime: new Date(2018, 7, 1, 9, 0),
    EndTime: new Date(2018, 7, 1, 10, 0),
    Description: "Health Checkup",
    DepartmentID: 1,
    ConsultantID: 1,
    DepartmentName: "GENERAL",
    CategoryColor: "Blue"
  }
```

and, apply this color field for the event while it's rendering by making use of **eventRendered** event like the below.

```
oneventRendered(args: EventRenderedArgs): void {
        let categoryColor: string = args.data.CategoryColor as string;
        if (!args.element || !categoryColor) {
            return;
        }
        if (this.scheduleObj.currentView === 'Agenda') {
            (args.element.firstChild as HTMLElement).style.borderLeftColor = categoryColor;
        } else {
            args.element.style.backgroundColor = categoryColor;
        }
    }
```

For more reference, please refer the below demo link and get back to us for further assistance.

Sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-udwvvf-fbm7mw?file=app.component.ts

UG Link: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/schedule/appointments/?no-cache=1#using-eventrendered-event

Comment: What about this one @vengatesh? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61796226/drag-and-drop-from-ej2-angular-scheduler-to-a-div

Comment: @etrupja I have posted the response in that query. please check and get back to us for further assistance.